# App::FatPacker on Windows

Tags: perl

I have a script on Windows which uses multiple pure Perl modules from CPAN.
I am trying to ship this script without the need to reinstall those modules from CPAN using `App::FatPacker`.

I installed `App::FatPacker`  ( up to date (0.010007) version ) on Portable Strawberry Perl 5.24 .

When I run the following command

```
fatpack pack myscript.pl > myscript.packed.pl
```

I get

> syntax OK

but the fatlib is empty and when I run my script it fails.

I tried to use this script which does nothing but load `Geo::IP::PurePerl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Geo::IP::PurePerl;
```

and run again this command :

```
fatpack pack myscript.pl > myscript.packed.pl
```

Then I ran `myscript.packed.pl` on another instance of Strawberry Perl 5.24, I get the following error:

> Can't locate Geo/IP/PurePerl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Geo::IP::PurePerl module

I tried to debug it by building step by step

The fatpack trace creates a trace list as expected, including `Geo::IP::PurePerl`

The fatpack packlists-for finished successfully but the fatlib is empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that `packlists-for` isn't finding any .packlist files

The documentation for `fatpack` says this

> **packlists-for**
>
> ```
> $ fatpack packlists-for Module1 Module2 Module3
> ```
>
> Searches your perl's @INC for .packlist files containing the .pm files for the modules requested and emits a list of unique packlist files to STDOUT.
>
> These packlists will, in a pure cpan-installation environment, be all non-core distributions required for those modules.
>
> Unfortunately most vendors strip the .packlist files so if you installed modules via e.g. apt-get you may be missing those modules; installing your dependencies into a `local::lib` first is the preferred workaround.

I think that's useful advice that may well fix your problem